# Deploy as ROOT in embedded tomcat

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, spring-tool-suite

I have a Spring Boot Application named my-app. I can package it as a war, deploy the war to an external tomcat server as ROOT.war and then access it from `localhost:8080`. But now if I run this application from Spring Tool Suite by using `Run As > Run On Server`, the application can be accessed from `localhost:8080/my-app`.

How can I make it accessible from `localhost:8080`?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Tomcat - making a project folder the web root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044129/tomcat-making-a-project-folder-the-web-root)

Comment: @Nikhil I don't think that link says anything about embedded tomcat. How can I edit the server.xml of embedded tomcat?

Comment: When you are deploying spring boot with `Run As > Run On Server` you are not using the embedded tomcat.

Comment: ahh, missed that you are using STS, in that case this question help:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12305077/testing-new-spring-mvc-project-in-sts-default-root-context

Comment: @SagarRohankar wow. I learnt something new today. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

change the `context-path` in `application.properties` to `/`, like

```
server.servlet.context-path=/
```

More options: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-context-path

Comment: which version of boot you are using, 1 or 2?

Comment: I'm using version 2.1.0.RELEASE